# loop over hosts in jinja2 template as variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm aware that Ansible supports loops in templates in this form:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
join= {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}:29016
{% endfor %}
```

I want to change the hosts Inventory to be dynamic and to take the hosts variable

E.g 
Imagine this setup:

```
# hosts
[testOne]
192.168.42.2
192.168.42.10 
192.168.42.20

[testTwo]
192.168.42.212
192.168.42.101 
192.168.42.202
```

## playbook.yml

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Hosts
      template: src=myhosts.j2 dest=./myhosts.json
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      run_once: yes

{% for host in groups['{{ hosts }}'] %}
join= {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}:29016
{% endfor %}
```

and run as:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -e"hosts=testTwo"
```

But Ansible does not know to interpret hosts variable to list and loop over it

Any help? 
Thanks!

Comment: Try `{% for host in groups[hosts] %}`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `--limit` to select your host(s) / group(s)

and `ansible_play_hosts_all` variable to loop on it.

---

Demo:

`hosts.ini`:

```
[group1]
host1 ansible_host=1.2.3.4 ansible_connection=local
host2 ansible_host=2.3.4.5 ansible_connection=local

[group2]
host3 ansible_host=3.4.5.6 ansible_connection=local
host4 ansible_host=4.5.6.7 ansible_connection=local
```

`play.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all -%} 
          {{ host }},  
          {%- endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: yes
```

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini play.yml --limit group1

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1 -> localhost] => {
    "msg": "host1,host2,\n"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini play.yml --limit host1,host3

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1 -> localhost] => {
    "msg": "host1,host3,\n"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```